# Django - CrispyForms - DecimalField - Validation Error Message

Tags: django

I have the following model and would like to ensure that
a) either the user is able to enter only numbers and a decimal point or
b) a custom validation error is displayed to the user to enter a decimal value only. I am using the **init** method and would like to include such validation in this method. Is it possible?. The CurrencyCode is a ForeignKey field so it has to appear as a dropdown on the rendered form.

[image]
Below is the code:

MODELS.PY:

```
class Forex(models.Model):
    currency_code = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    forex_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
    last_updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Forex Rates"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency_code.currency_code
```

---

FORMS.PY:

```
class ForexForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = Forex
      fields = ['currency_code', 'forex_rate']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ForexForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['currency_code'].error_messages = {'required': 'Currency Code Cannot Be Blank',
                                                   'unique': 'Forex Rate Already Exists!'
                                                   }
        self.fields['forex_rate'].error_messages = {'required': 'Forex Rate Cannot Be Blank'}
```

---

VIEWS.PY:

```
def forex_add(request):
    form = ForexForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, msg_add)
        return redirect('forex_list_page')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'main/forex_add.html', context)
```

---

FOREX_ADD/HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" novalidate>

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            {{ form.currency_code|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            {{ form.forex_rate|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit"><i
                class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i> Save
        </button>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="{% url 'forex_list_page' %}">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-reply"></i> Cancel</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

[image]I have managed to achieve two objectives a) Forex Rate field Cannot Be Blank and b) Forex Rate field should be greater than 1.00, by making the following changes. If I enter alphabets in the Forex Rate field, the alphabets are cleared on POST and I get the Forex Rate Cannot Be Blank message. I also get Django's default validation error message for the minimum value (if < 1.0). Could this have been done in a better way? The screenshot is from Firefox browser.

---

MODELS.PY:

```
class Forex(models.Model):
    currency_code = models.OneToOneField(Currency, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Forex')
    forex_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=4, null=False, blank=False, default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('1.00'))])
    last_updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Forex Rates"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency_code.currency_code
```

---

FORMS.PY:

```
def validate_forex_rate(value):
   format(value)


class ForexForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Forex
       fields = ['currency_code', 'forex_rate']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(ForexForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields["forex_rate"].validators.append(validate_forex_rate)
       self.fields['currency_code'].error_messages = {'required': 'Currency Code Cannot Be Blank', 'unique': 'Forex Rate Already Exists!'}
       self.fields['forex_rate'].error_messages = {'required': 'Forex Rate Cannot Be Blank'}
```